# MIPS assembly code about Fibonacci function

Tags: mips, fibonacci

I am working on a Fibonacci function using MIPS assembly code, which initially make F(0) = F(1) = 1, and produces two results: $v0 for indicating whether the n for F(n) is negetive or not(the value is 0 when negative, 1 when 0 or positive), and $v1 for the function results. Below is my code for this:

```
.data

newline:
  .asciiz "\n"

str0:
  .asciiz "Enter a positive integer: "

str1:
  .asciiz "ERROR\n"

str2:
  .asciiz "Result: "

.text

fibonacci:
  addi $sp, $sp, -12
  sw $ra, 8($sp)
  sw $s0, 4($sp)
  sw $s1, 0($sp)
  move $s0, $a0
  li $s1, 1
  bgtz $s0, loop
  add $zero, $zero, $zero
  li $v0, 1
  j exit

loop:
  beq $s0, 1, exit
  add $zero, $zero, $zero
  add $t0, $s1, $zero
  add $s1, $s1, $s0
  move $s0, $t0
  addi $s0, $s0, -1
  j loop

exit: 
  move $v1, $s1
  lw $ra, 8($sp)
  lw $s0, 4($sp)
  lw $s1, 0($sp)
  addi $sp, $sp, 12
  bltz $a0, negative
  add $zero, $zero, $zero
  li $v0, 1
  j return

negative:
  li $v0, 0
  j return

return:
  jr $ra


.globl main
main:
  # print_string str0
  li $v0, 4
  la $a0, str0
  syscall

  # $t0 = read_int
  li $v0, 5
  syscall
  move $t0, $v0

  # $s0 = $ra; fibonacci($t0); $ra = $s0
  move $s0, $ra
  move $a0, $t0
  jal fibonacci
  move $ra, $s0

  # $t0 = $v0; $t1 = $v1
  move $t0, $v0
  move $t1, $v1

  # if ($t0 == 0) { goto main_failure }
  beq $t0, $zero, main_failure

main_success:
  # print_string str2
  li $v0, 4
  la $a0, str2
  syscall

  # print_int $t1
  li $v0, 1
  move $a0, $t1
  syscall

  # print_string newline
  li $v0, 4
  la $a0, newline
  syscall

  # goto main_return
  b main_return

main_failure: 
  # print_string str1
  li $v0, 4
  la $a0, str1
  syscall

main_return:
  # return
  jr $ra
```

When I run this code using Spim, for the input 0, 1, and negative number, the result comes out correctly. However, with the positive integer bigger than 1, the result is "Arithmetic overflow". How can I fix this?

Comment: Are accumulating the Fibonacci numbers in $t0 and $s1?  Because you're adding $s0, and that's counting DOWN.

Comment: @TimRoberts Are you taking about "add $s1 $s1 $s0" part? I put that code for "f(n) = f(n-1) + f(n-2)", but is it wrong...?

Comment: Either you're using branch delay slots or not.  If you are, then the `j` and `jr` have them too.

Comment: *is it wrong?*  -- Yes.  $s0 does not contain `f(n-2)`.  It contains a decrementing counter, starting from the passed value in `$s0` counting down to 1.  Right?  I think you've used one register for two purposes.

Comment: Single step through with a small number, like 2, for the argument.  That will show you why it doesn't stop properly with the right answer.  (A likely reason for overflow is that it doesn't stop when it should.)